# How can I determine if two mathematical expressions are 'sort of' the same?

Tags: ios, expression

Sorry about the vagueness of this question, and maybe I want a different exchange? Not sure. Anyway, here goes:

I'd like to be able to determine if two mathematical expressions are 'the same'. I don't need full equivalence testing, which I understand is impossible anyway. Basically, I'd like to make a function that looks like this:

areTheSame(expression1, expression2, [testing methods])

where [testing methods] might include: 'exact', 'allow commutativity', 'allow distribution', ...

- 'exact' would be easy: expression1 == expression2 if their strings
  are exactly equal
- 'allow commutativity' would be more difficult. For instance, if
  expression1 is y=3*x and expression2 is y=x*3, then under 'allow
  commutativity', they would be the same. Ditto here for 'y=x' and 'x=y'.
- 'allow distribution' would allow 'y=2*(x-3)' to be equal to
  'y=2*x-6'.
- others?

Ideally, I'd like to be lazy! I'd love to find some library that

1. supports parsing expressions from latex representations (or MathML, which is xml already, maybe it's easier to parse)
2. supports equivalence testing with some flags or something that
   govern how exact the comparison should be, as above.
3. is written in c or c++ (or Objective-C - this is for an iOS project)
4. is not GPL.

4 rules out SymbolicC++ and GiNaC afaik. Mathomatic is LGPL, which I'm not sure about in the context of apple's app-Store (and I would really not like to have to give out object files)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer, but it's too long to be a comment. :)

My first thought: this is not an easy or common problem, so you probably won't have much luck finding a library to do it for you. Finding a library that does some of the non-critical parts, on the other hand, shouldn't be difficult.

What you probably want to do is parse the expressions to create an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (you'll probably find lots of libraries for that), then recursively analyze the AST yourself to test whatever definition of sameness you're after.

In iOS, a decent place to start might be (horribly ab)using [`NSExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) and [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). These have constructor methods that parse a string and return a structure of expression and predicate objects.

Recursively walk that structure. For each predicate, check to see if the `predicateOperatorType` matches... if it doesn't, the predicates aren't the same. If it does, look at the left predicate's `leftExpression` and the right predicate's `leftExpression`. Each expression has a `function` that tells you what its operator is (add, subtract, etc). If they don't match, the expressions aren't the same. (Do the same check for the other side.) If they do, recurse: look at each expression's sub-expressions and do a similar check, and so on until you get to expressions that are constant values or variables.

That's a rough sketch of how to see if two predicates (and the expressions they contain) "match". For "sort of the same", just relax each check you perform while recursively walking the tree and/or add more checks; e.g. if you get to an expression whose function is `add`, check for commutativity by comparing its sub-expressions to the corresponding ones in the other predicate in either order. (Also, there are probably other libraries that'll parse basic math expressions and get you an AST you can walk however you like.)

That still won't get you everything you're after — "allow distribution" gets you into the realm of full-fledged [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) software. Maybe look into whether the likes of Wolfram Alpha have web service APIs?